# Save BOTH handout + standard beamer pdf outputs

Tags: beamer, xetex, pdf

Is it possible to configure LaTeX to simultaneously output a standard .pdf for a presentation and also a handout version?

Platform: Texmaker
Compiler: XeLaTeX

Comment: No, only one PDF file can be output per TeX run.

Comment: In addition to the other link, I'm sure I've answered this using arara somewhere on this site